# Resharper color transparency option

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

What is the option in Resharper where I can change the transparency based on rules?

As you can see below, the "this" qualifier is transparent on my machine but I don't know which option is in charge of that.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This "greying out" is marking redundant code. Your code style settings are saying that you don't want to see qualifiers such as `this.`. You can change this setting in ReSharper's options → Code Editing → C# → Code Style.

[image]

Comment: But can you change the colour of redundant code? I couldn't find a setting in VS Fonts and Colors

Comment: No, you can't change the colour. Redundant code is "greyed out", to show that it's still valid, just not doing anything useful. In VS, this just means it's some kind of alpha blend, so makes it transparent. So the code retains its normal colouring (the screenshot in the original post is a keyword, coloured blue), but it's alpha faded into the background.